# submitHandler is an invalid label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

Below is the code, I get an error which says that `submitHandler` is an invalid label

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#withdraw").validate({ 
            rules: { 
             amount: {
                required: true,
                 number:true,
                 min:0,
                 max:<?php echo $balance; ?>

            } ,
            bank:{
                required:true,

            },
            cardnumber1: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:8

            },
           cardnumber2:{
              required:true,
              equalTo: "#cardnumber1"
             },
              holder:{
              required:true,
            }
      }
    }),
       submitHandler: function(form){
           var answer = confirm("Do you really want to withdraw this amount of money from your account?")
        if (answer){
            form.submit();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }   
      }
    });
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: var answer = confirm("Do you really want to withdraw this amount of money from your account?") ;

Comment: at the end of your code -->  );    where does it start..?

Comment: . this is shouldn't be community wiki..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing brace and parent here, just before `submitHandler`, this: `}),` should just be: `,`  The brace before it closes the rules object.